# Good list of theorems tobprove

Tags: formal-proofs

HI I am a highschooler currently taking calc BC and I am looking for some fun theorems I could try to prove. I have proved a lot of trigonometric identities and the fundemental theorem of calculus and I am looking for some new challenges. Especially ones that require relatively little background knowledge and more critical thinking.

Comment: Have you done the proof of why $\sqrt 2$ is irrational?

Comment: 'Substitution formula' theorem is a simple one, if you know the fundamental theorem of calculus. How (from what assumptions) did you prove this?

Comment: There are infinitely many prime numbers.

Comment: There are infinitely many primes of the form 6n+5 with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions I have  proven those now and have a new problem if you could read my post about it and help it would be much appreciated